# Freezegun always causes RuntimeWarning of receiving naive datetime

Tags: django, timezone, freezegun

I'm working with a testcase where an organization can be suspended.
Currently I'm using `freezegun` to freeze a firm time, which is a `datetime.datetime` object with `tzinfo=pytz.UTC`.

In the test below you'll see a print of `self.fake_datetime` which returns a `tzaware` datetime: `2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`.

When the test runs, I keep getting the famous `RuntimeWarning`:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:1447: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Organization.suspended received a naive datetime (2000-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
>     RuntimeWarning)

```
import datetime
import pytz

from freezegun import freeze_time
# crop

class OrganizationSuspendTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.organization = OrganizationFactory()
        self.fake_datetime = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
        print self.fake_datetime

    def test_suspend_organization(self):
        """
        Case: An organization is being suspended with the suspend service.
        Expected: The organization is updated with the suspending datetime and the reason.
        """
        with freeze_time(self.fake_datetime):
            mc_organization.services.organization.suspend(organization=self.organization, reason="Did not pay the bill")

        self.assertEqual(self.organization.suspended, datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

I've been playing around with the [freezegun timezone examples](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun#timezones) without any success to remove the runtime warning.

Any suggestions on how this should be resolved properly? I'd like to keep using `Freezegun` for this without a `RuntimeWarning`. Suppressing is an option, but I'd prefer not to.

**update** -- Solution based on the [answer of xyres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50262927/3202958)

Service was saving the datetime timezone unaware. Old situation commented and new situation is the actual code. I was thinking to much about `mocking` and assumed that the datetime saved in the `service` would be mocked with the timezone aware datetime object from the testcase by `freezegun` - which is not the case.

```
def suspend(organization, reason):
    """
    Suspend an organization with the given reason.
    :param mc_organization.models.Organization organization: The organization to suspend.
    :param string reason: The reason of the suspending.
    :return: None
    """
    # organization.suspended = datetime.datetime.now() (Old sitation)
    organization.suspended = timezone.now()  # timezone aware situation.
    organization.suspended_reason = reason
    organization.save()
```

Comment: As a shortcut, you can replace this line - `timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now())` - with [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) which will automatically return the timezone-aware `now` time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're [trying to save an object with a timezone-naive datetime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#code). To get rid of this warning, just use timezone-aware datetime everywhere in your application.

---

Instead of managing timezone yourself manually using `pytz`, you can use Django's `timezone` module found at [`django.utils.timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone) . It has some shortcut methods that you can use to convert naive datetime to aware datetime.

An advantage of using this is that if you ever change the timezone settings in your settings file, it will automatically pick the new timezone, whereas with `pytz` you'll have to manually update the new timezone everywhere.

```
from django.utils import timezone

fake_datetime = timezone.make_aware(timezone.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was expecting the datetime object was mocked during the test with `freezegun`, which was an incorrect assumption. I've updated my question with the fix from your answer and described my wrong assumption.